# JQuery blur action doesn't work

Tags: jquery

```
$("#rods_number").blur(function(){
  $("#rodform").empty();
  $("#rodform").slideDown();
  var rods = document.forms['rods_number'].rods_number.value;
  console.log(rods);
  for (var x = 0 ; x < rods ; x++)
  {
    $("#rodform").append('<tr><td><input type="text" class="sub_input_box" id="rod_legnth" name="rod_length[]"></td><td><p class= "input_label">طـول الـعود</p></td><td><input type="number" class="sub_input_box" id="rod_count" name="rod_count[]"></td><td><p class= "input_label">عدد الاعـواد</p></tr>');
  }
});
```

When I replace `blur` by `keyup`, it works fine, using `blur` or `focus` is not working

Comment: Check for errors in your console

Comment: it shows no error , the code run prefect only by replacing blur by keyup

Comment: any way the way your try to trigger the blur event  is not good ?

Answer (score 0):

`blur` is a build in function so how can you can't work with it?

http://jsbin.com/xerofew/edit?js,output

Comment: I dont know but it dosnt make sense to me when i replace by another action and it works

Comment: So do you mean you want when ever the `#rods_number` is `keyup` then it will fire up the code?